# Laravel - likes package

Tags: ajax, laravel, social-likes

I import likes package `overtrue/laravel-follow` in my project and it shows me error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'likes.followables' doesn't exist (SQL: select exists(select * from `posts` inner join `followables` on `posts`.`id` = `followables`.`followable_id` where `followables`.`user_id` = 1 and `followables`.`followable_type` = App\Post and `followables`.`relation` = like and `id` = 1) as `exists`) (View: C:\engineering\xampp\htdocs\likes\resources\views\posts.blade.php)

This is my `HomeController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        $posts = Post::get();
        return view('posts', compact('posts'));
    }


    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function ajaxRequest(Request $request){


        $post = Post::find($request->id);
        $response = auth()->user()->toggleLike($post);


        return response()->json(['success'=>$response]);
    }
}
```

My `Post.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanBeLiked;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use CanBeLiked;


    protected $fillable = ['title'];
}
```

My `posts.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />


<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Posts</div>


                <div class="card-body">
                    @if($posts->count())
                        @foreach($posts as $post)
                            <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="panel panel-info" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <a href="https://itsolutionstuff.com/upload/itsolutionstuff.png" title="Nature Portfolio" data-title="Amazing Nature" data-footer="The beauty of nature" data-type="image" data-toggle="lightbox">
                                            <img src="https://itsolutionstuff.com/upload/itsolutionstuff.png" alt="Nature Portfolio" />
                                            <span class="overlay"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <h4><a href="#" title="Nature Portfolio">{{ $post->title }}</a></h4>
                                        <span class="pull-right">
                                            <span class="like-btn">
                                                <i id="like{{$post->id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up {{ auth()->user()->hasLiked($post) ? 'like-post' : '' }}"></i> <div id="like{{$post->id}}-bs3">{{ $post->likers()->get()->count() }}</div>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {     


        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        $('i.glyphicon-thumbs-up, i.glyphicon-thumbs-down').click(function(){    
            var id = $(this).parents(".panel").data('id');
            var c = $('#'+this.id+'-bs3').html();
            var cObjId = this.id;
            var cObj = $(this);


            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'/ajaxRequest',
               data:{id:id},
               success:function(data){
                  if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data.success.attached)){
                    $('#'+cObjId+'-bs3').html(parseInt(c)-1);
                    $(cObj).removeClass("like-post");
                  }else{
                    $('#'+cObjId+'-bs3').html(parseInt(c)+1);
                    $(cObj).addClass("like-post");
                  }
               }
            });


        });      


        $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).ekkoLightbox();
        });                                        
    }); 
</script>
@endsection
```

My `web.php` :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('posts', 'HomeController@posts')->name('posts');
Route::post('ajaxRequest', 'HomeController@ajaxRequest')->name('ajaxRequest');
```

And my `User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanLike;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use CanLike, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Why is it showing me this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'likes.followables' doesn't exist (SQL: select exists(select * from `posts` inner join `followables` on `posts`.`id` = `followables`.`followable_id` where `followables`.`user_id` = 1 and `followables`.`followable_type` = App\Post and `followables`.`relation` = like and `id` = 1) as `exists`) (View: C:\engineering\xampp\htdocs\likes\resources\views\posts.blade.php)

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you follow the publishing and migration instructions on the page for that package? Specifically `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Overtrue\LaravelFollow\FollowServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"` followed by `php artisan migrate` See https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow#installation for full installation instructions.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes I did Sir, everything like it said on that page

Comment: Then your post should probably include that information, cause at a glance, all you said was you imported it, which is pretty vague. Maybe consider opening an issue on that actual package: https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow/issues

Comment: @TimLewis Sir right now I did ```php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Overtrue\LaravelFollow\FollowServiceProvider' --tag="migrations"``` again followed by ```php artisan migrate``` and it works. Maybe there was some "unfollowed" step

Comment: Clearly that step was missed. As a general rule, if you ever get a `Base table or view not found` error, it has to do with a missing or invalid (spelling, case, etc) table, and you should check your database for that table/your app for missing migrations, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis I know that of course and I was amazed by that problem ```Base table or view not found``` but I tought I followed every step properly. Thank you Sir for noticing it

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it working :)